# Show/hide DatePicker wheel manually in SwiftUI

Tags: datepicker, show-hide, swiftui

I want to dismiss the keyboard when tapping out of a textfield, in order to give space to a picker below that textfield.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var date = Date()
    @State private var text = "write something...."

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField(text, text: $text)
            }

            Section {
                DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date, label: { Text("select a date")})
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.dismissKeyboard()
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

The problem is the `.onTapGesture` does dismiss the keyboard but it doesn't show the picker wheel. So, is there a way to call the hidden wheel after dismiss the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.onAppear` instead of `.onTapGesture`

```
 DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date, label: { Text("select a date")})
   .onAppear {
      self.dismissKeyboard()
   }
```